# How can I run a Face-API query against images stored in an azure data store blob?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I have 200k images stored in an blob on an Azure storage account (also linked from a Data Lake Storage account). I would like to run Face detection on all of them so that I can add them to a LargeFaceList. The first step is running Face detection.

The following snippet (copied from tutorials) works fine for doing Face detection on a web image:

```
import cognitive_face as CF
KEY = 'mykey'
BASE_URL = 'https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/'
CF.Key.set(KEY)
CF.BaseUrl.set(BASE_URL)
CF.face.detect('https://images.fastcompany.net/image/upload/w_596,c_limit,q_auto:best,f_auto,fl_lossy/fc/3068134-inline-i-1-warren-buffet-gave-bill-gates-30-billion-heres-how-its-paying-off.jpg')
```

What I would like to do is run a similar query against images stored in my azure blob.

In USQL I would do something like:

```
"wasb://[blob_name]@[storage_account_name]/FileName.png"
```

But not surprisingly this doesn't work because the `KEY` defined above is the key to the face api service, not to my azure storage, so it has no way (I don't think) to find that data.

How can I do this? I don't want to have to upload my 200k images one-by-one to the Face detector!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access the file instead as:

```
https://[storage_account_name].blob.core.windows.net/[blob_name]/FileName.png
```

If the blob is not accessible publicly, you can tack on [Shared Access Signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1) to give the API temporary access to the file.

You of course will still need to call the API one image at a time, as there is no batch mechanism.  This also means you will be subject to the rate/quota limits for your account.